# Ошибка 'return' outside function- как решить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 2 файла. При запуске generate_page должна произойти запись строки в файл index.html.
Сейчас при запуске на локальном сервере в консоли такие ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programming\Python\kyb\mod3 html\3\generate_all.py", line 3, in <module>
    from horoscope import generate_prophecies
  File "D:\programming\Python\kyb\mod3 html\3\horoscope.py", line 26
    return prophecies
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

**horoscope.py**

```
import random
times = ["утром", "днем", "вечером", "ночью", "после обеда", "перед сном"]
advices = ["ожидайте", "предостерегайтесь", "будьте открыты для"]
promises = ["гостей из забытого прошлого", "встреч со старыми знакомыми",
            "неожиданного праздника", "приятных перемен"]


def generate_prophecies(total_num=5, num_sentences=3):
    prophecies = []


for i in range(total_num):
    forecast = ""
for j in range(num_sentences):
    t = random.choice(times)
    a = random.choice(advices)
    p = random.choice(promises)

    full_sentence = f"{t.title()} {a} {p}."
    if j != num_sentences - 1:
        full_sentence = full_sentence + " "

    forecast = forecast + full_sentence
    prophecies.append(forecast)

    return prophecies
```

**generate_all.py**

```
# coding: utf-8

from horoscope import generate_prophecies
from datetime import datetime as dt


def generate_page(head, body):
    page = f"<html>{head}{body}</html>"
    return page


def generate_head(title):
    head = f"""<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    """
    return head


def generate_body(header, paragraphs):
    body = f"<h1>{header}</h1>"
    for p in paragraphs:
        body = body + f"<p>{p}</p>"
    return f"<body>{body}</body>"


def save_page(title, header, paragraphs, output="index.html"):
    fp = open(output, "w")
    today = dt.now().date()
    page = generate_page(
        head=generate_head(title),
        body=generate_body(header=header, paragraphs=paragraphs)
    )
    print(page, file=fp)
    fp.close()

#####################


today = dt.now().date()

save_page(
    title="Гороскоп на сегодня",
    header="Что день " + str(today) + " готовит",
    paragraphs=generate_prophecies(),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберитесь с отступами в horoscope.py. В таком виде работает:

```
import random

times = ["утром", "днем", "вечером", "ночью", "после обеда", "перед сном"]
advices = ["ожидайте", "предостерегайтесь", "будьте открыты для"]
promises = ["гостей из забытого прошлого", "встреч со старыми знакомыми",
        "неожиданного праздника", "приятных перемен"]

def generate_prophecies(total_num=5, num_sentences=3):
    prophecies = []
    for i in range(total_num):
        forecast = ""
        for j in range(num_sentences):
            t = random.choice(times)
            a = random.choice(advices)
            p = random.choice(promises)
            full_sentence = f"{t.title()} {a} {p}."
            if j != num_sentences - 1:
                full_sentence = full_sentence + " "
    forecast = forecast + full_sentence
    prophecies.append(forecast)
    return prophecies
```

Comment: Alex P Да, запускает, только что-то с кодировкой, все в ромбах выводит, хотя файл в utf-8

Comment: Уберите строку "<meta charset='utf-8'>" из функции generate_head.